# Some problem in Migrate MySQL database to PostgreSQL using EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, enterprisedb

I understand you must be extremely busy with your new project, so I will just be brief.

​   I'm trying to convert my MySQL database to PostgreSQL using EnterpriseDB Migration Tool. My setup is as follows:

- Windows 10 x64
- MySQL 5.6.33
- EDB PostgreSQL 10.12
- EnterpriseDB Migration Toolkit 53.0.2

1. I want change **char** type in Mysql to **character varying** to postgresql ddl;
2. And some col in Mysql like **userId** to postgres, but expected "**userId**" in pg ddl;

Here is an example in mysql:

```sql
create table test
(
    testcol char(2),
    userId  varchar(32)
);
```

conver by Toolkit:

```sql
create table test
(
    testcol char(2),
    "userId" varchar(32)
);
```

I expect:

```sql
create table test
(
    testcol varchar(2),
    userid varchar(32)
);
```

​   I found command `-customColTypeMapping` in docs, but it perhaps not works in my scenario.

​    So, is there any solutions to resolve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: why do you expect 'userId' to change to 'userid'?  customColTypeMapping lets you specify a regular expression for column names to change to a given type; it doesn't seem to let you change all of a particular type to another type

Comment: When i have "userId" in postgresql, some other problem occured.Like select this column or use mybatis to maaping database.So lower case is my expect

Comment: as shown in the conversion, you need to put mixed case column/table names in double quotes to use them.

Comment: @shaking Can you please share me a command used to migrate, i am facing issue while adding sourcetype in command